# .Net, WebClient, DownloadString fails for one site ("The underlying connection was closed...")

Tags: .net, ssl, webclient

I'm accessing many sites using .Net (Framework 3.5) in a similar way to get data (used for Wikipedia). Now I encountered one site I'm not able to access. I get an exception "The underlying connection was closed". The site uses SSL (https), but I don't know if this raises the problem. I've read many threads and tried many suggestions but nothing worked for me yet. I've also tried OpenRead / ReadToEnd, it fails too. I must admit that my knowledge about HTTP ist very limited.

The site is https://www.infoflora.ch.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

JER

Here my code sample:

```
class WebClientDBLink : WebClient
{
    public WebClientDBLink()
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Headers.Add("Content-Type", Bot.webContentType);
        Headers.Add("User-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        // wr.KeepAlive = false;
        // wr.Timeout = 100000;
        return wr;
    }
}
...

    String sUrl = "https://www.infoflora.ch/de/flora/2906-.html"; // just one exampl

    String sText = "";

    try
    {

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        Uri res = new Uri(sUrl);
        WebClient wc = new WebClientDBLink();
        sText = wc.DownloadString(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this on Windows XP?

Comment: Yes, it's running on Windows XP. Sorry that I forgot this.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> The site uses SSL (https), but I don't know if this raises the problem.

in conjunction with your comment:

> Yes, it's running on Windows XP

gives a hint :)

The endpoint at `https://infoflora.ch` only supports fairly modern cipher suites (AES and CAMELLIA in CBC mode and AES-GCM) - none of which are supported on Windows XP.

Use Windows 7 or newer if you want this to work (you know that Windows XP is no longer supported right?)

Comment: You are right! It runs under Windows 7 without any problems! (with "no longer supported" you are right too, but...). Respect for figuring out this problem with such little information. Many thanks!